# cannt access server when change to other network

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, webserver

I deployed a laravel project to AWS beanstalk. It's ok when I access server from my company wifi but have a problem when i try to connect from other network(4g, other network). 
When use mycompany wifi:

```
boisu013noMacBook-puro:~ voice013$ host enst-world.com
enst-world.com has address 52.196.32.10
enst-world.com has address 54.178.133.11
```

when use 4G

```
boisu013noMacBook-puro:~ voice013$ host enst-world.com
Host enst-world.com not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
boisu013noMacBook-puro:~ voice013$ host enst-world.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I tried to fix it during 3 days but could not.anybody here can help me. 
I am really grateful for that.